# preg_match - get match with just one statement

Tags: php, regex

I am wondering if it's possible to get a regex match in PHP by only using one statement? This question is more of a challenge to see if this is possible.

Right now you have to do something like this:

```
preg_match('#(\d+)$#', $subject, $match);
echo $match[1];
```

How do I access `$match` with one statement, instead of two?

I don't want to use `preg_replace`.

If it's possible with a closure, the better. I love fancy code.

Comment: A complete list of all preg_* functions: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's possbile. the third argument `$matches` is always an array. From the PHP docs:

> If matches is provided, then it is filled with the results of search.
>   $matches[0] will contain the text that matched the full pattern,
>   $matches[1] will have the text that matched the first captured
>   parenthesized subpattern, and so on.

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

If you have a lot of regexes that only have one group of capturing parentheses, you could make a shortcut function for your purpose:

```
function preg_match_one($regex, $subject) {

    if(preg_match($regex, $subject, $matches)) {
        return $matches[1];
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: I just wish that `preg_match` would return `$match` instead of how many occurrences were found. If someone was interested in that you could use `count() - 1` or let `$match` be `&$count` where that value would be saved.
Your answer wasn't what I was aiming for but I'll accept it for having made an effort.

Comment: @silkfire That's how `preg_match` is implemented, which means there is no other way than creating such a function. If you still insist, then go dive into the internals of PHP and modify the C source code, I bet you'll prefere this method :)